# How to show indication for bash script commands execution using exec in php?

Tags: php, bash

I have a bash script file `"myApp.sh"` that include many commands (for loops, building DB, import data to DB, calling other bash scripts files). The commands are complicated.

I am invoking this `"myApp.sh"` from a PHP page using `exce` method:

```
$contents = file_get_contents('../myApp.sh');
$output = null;
$return_var = null;
$contents = escapeshellarg($contents);
exec("/usr/local/bin/bash -c $contents 2>&1", $output, $return_var);
  echo "<hr>";
  print_r($output);
echo "<hr>";
```

Now, I would like to show loading or percentage progress bar for the user because the commands sometimes takes more than 15 minutes to finish.

How could I show some progress bar for the user? or show the output of each command simultaneously while running?

Note: the function `proc_open` not works with my scripts it stops when facing for loop or invoking another scripts file. Thus, the only function that works for my scripts is `exec`

Answer (score 0):

I have written such a script in the past, usint tput utility.

https://github.com/realSpok/progressbar

You can use it this way:

```
progress $k $total
```

Comment: How could I use it in PHP? I want to show progress of the scripts that being executing I do not know the target number of iteration. The problem is that the exec shows the script output after finishing all commands.

Comment: I am not sure how you would be able to track your progress of you cannot get an iteration variable of some kind